# How do I assign a default value to a function parameter that is a function? C++

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

Let's say you have a function like this:

```
int Function(int a = 5, int b = 10){
...
}
```

When you call the same function with fewer parameters then it should have, for example:

```
int var = Function(8);
```

'a' becomes 8, and 'b' gets the default value 10;

With this in mind, let's say I have another function called Function3 that receives another function as its argument:

```
    int Function3(int x, int Function2 (int)){
        ...
    int m = Function2(x);
        ...
    return m;
    }
```

How do I set the default function (function2) that should be called if I do not send any function as an argument to Function3 (using the lambda functions)?

So if I do this:

```
int ver = Function3(y);
```

instead of this:

```
int ver = Function3(y,std::sin)
```

How do I tell it to, for example, multiply the number with 3 if nothing has been sent as a third argument? (and if it has to use that function to work with x and y).

Comment: `std::sin` is not an `int(int)` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameter should be a pointer to a function, and you can assign this like any other parameter.

```
int Function3(int a, int b, int (*func)(int,int) = Function2)    
{
  func(a,b); //call will use passed function, or Function2 if one wasn't provided
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is that I make the default value be `NULL`, and then in the implementation of the function I begin with an `if` statement which checks whether `NULL` was passed for that parameter, and if so, uses the intended default instead.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel and introduce a branch into your program?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Well, I did not know that the OP's problem could be trivially solved, I thought that the OP's difficulty was that the default value that he wanted to pass was not in scope, or was otherwise unavailable, in some of the places where the call is being made.

Comment: The scope of the callsite is irrelevant to default arguments